# How to access application context from another module of same application?

Tags: android

I have two modules of same application, having different Manifest files, Main App is in first Module, I want to access to Main App Context in second module. Can someone Please help if it is possible then how can I access this.

Comment: I want to access in activity for Dependency injection(DI), as for DI I have to access my application.

Answer (score -2):

You should create a class, that will extends Application. It will be your Application instance that will be alive during application lifecycle. And you can use it in every part or your code (especially for DI). You should create static Application field for this inside your Application class. 
Don't forget to note your Application class in Android manifest.

Comment: But then also how the secondary module access that class object, as secondary module depends upon main module

Comment: I suppose that your Presentation module should depends on Context because it is Android feature. Your data and domain modules shouldn't depend on it.

Comment: There are BaseActivity, BaseFragment etc and some error notification class in my secondary module, and all activities, fragments extends that base classes in my main module (MVP architecture), I want to access AppComponent(DI component) and getapplication in base classes

Comment: As I understand you want to use Context inside presentation module. Well just create Application class and you can access to this from Base classes.
If you use Dagger 2 just create an Interface for your component, create instance inside your Application class, and using DaggerYourComponentName.builder() install all modules to your component and build it. After that you can use it anywhere where you call your Application.getYourComponent() and call methods for injection.